# Change "return key" in an iPhone WebApp textbox

Tags: iphone, keyboard, web-applications, key, return

I am creating an iPhone webapp with a textbox and would like to change the return key to "search".  When you click on the textbox, the keyboard pops up and the return key on the bottom right of the keyboard displays "return" by default.

However if you go to google.com on your iPhone and click on the search textbox the return key on the  bottom right displays "Go", while yahoo.com's search box displays "Search".  I tried looking through google and yahoos source code but couldn't find any specific property they are using to do this.

This is a webapp and not a native app.

** Update - 9/12/2011 **

google.com's search textbox now displays "Search" for the return key instead of "Go"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out..

you have to add **title="Search"** to the textbox AND the textbox must be within the FORM tags.

Example:

```
<FORM ...>
   <INPUT TYPE="text" TITLE="Search" ...>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Downside to this approach is non iOS (desktop) users will see "Search" displayed as a tooltip when they mouse over the input field. Not ideal. I guess you have to specifically add this attribute to the field using javascript when showing to iOS devices.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with custom text though... Like if I want the button to say Login, that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

iOS supports the [`search` input type](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#text-%28type=text%29-state-and-search-state-%28type=search%29):

```
<form>
    <input type=search>
</form>
```